# How to set field values for the table field type in Craft 3

Tags: modules, table-field

I'm trying to insert an entry along with values for a table field. According to the [docs](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-base-element.html#method-setfieldvalues), the `setFieldValues` method takes an array of values in the format `handle => value`, but it doesn't specify how the value should be formatted for each field type.

Here's my best guess at how it might work for the table field:

```php
$entry = new Entry();
$entry->sectionId = 1;
$entry->typeId = 1;
$entry->title = $title;
$entry->setFieldValues([
  "field_handle" => [
    ["column_1_handle" => "hello", "column_2_handle" => "world"], // Row 1
    ["column_1_handle" => "more", "column_2_handle" => "stuff"] // Row 2
  ]
]);
```

This inserts the correct number of rows into the table field, but the values are empty, so I'm guessing I'm structuring the array incorrectly.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

I figured this out. The table field is expecting JSON:

```php
$entry = new Entry();
$entry->sectionId = 1;
$entry->typeId = 1;
$entry->title = $title;
$entry->setFieldValues([
  "field_handle" => '[{"col1":"hello","col2":"world"},{"col1":"more","col2":"stuff"}]'
]);
```

Comment: Great answer thank you! There is the `json_encode([ 'col1' => 'hello', 'col2' => 'world' ])` which may be useful for others :)